# NiCd 60Ah battery application

Tags: battery-charging, batteries, nicd-battery

What is the application of 1.2v ,60Ah NiCd(pocket type) battery now. Is it still in use in substations?

Comment: It's a battery and batteries are used for portable equipment (inside a sub station or outside a sub station or even on the moon or mars)

Comment: 60Ah batteries ?  Is it suitable for protection circuit in a substation or applications like UPS .. considering the charging and discharging time